# Similar Matrices and Characteristic Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is a well known fact that if two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar, then they have the same characteristic polynomial i.e. det($xI-A$)=det($xI-B$). I think that the converse must also be true. As a matter of fact, if $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalizable, it is easy to see this. My question is : What if $A$ and $B$ are not diagonalizable?

Comment: For a counter example, consider $A=0$ and $B$ nilpotent.

Comment: ok, thanks! aside from nilpotent matrices, are there other matrices that can be used as counter examples?

Comment: Just add $id$ to $A$ and $B$ and the conclusion remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. For example, each of the following five (nilpotent) matrices have $x^4$ as the characteristic polynomial. No two are similar. Only the first is diagonalizable.

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
For more information, including how I constructed these counter-examples, look at [the Jordan Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) and [the Frobenius Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form). These two canonical forms gives a complete description for matrix similarity, much like the diagonal form does for diagonalizable matrices. You'll see that it's also simple to construct examples which are not nilpotent.